# mongo db count query for case insensitivity

Tags: regex, mongodb

how following can be achieve with/without regex

let empName = 'ABC';

db.emp.count({name:empName});

it should consider case insensitivy and ignore leading and trailing spaces.

ex: empName could be 'abc', 'abc   ', '  Abc   ' or ' AbC '.
for all above examples query should return 1.

Comment: Use [`abc`](https://regex101.com/r/mj4XBY/1) with `global` and `case-insensitive` flag

Answer (score -1):

You can just use regex to achieve this:

```
db.emp.count({"name" : /^abc$/i});
```

But do note that case-insensitive queries won't use an index and scan the whole collection.

More information can be found on the MongoDB docs - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-case-insensitive-regular-expression-match